# For every subset $A$ of $X$, $f(\overline{A})$ is a subset of $\overline{f(A)}$

Tags: general-topology

[image: Why does f(x) belongsto closure of F(A)]

looking at the image above, the line $3 \to 4$, I can't seem to understand why $f(x)$ belongs to the closure of $f(A)$ and how it implies that $f(\overline{A})$ is a subset of $\overline{f(A)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The author took a $x\in\overline A$ and proved that, for any neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $V\cap f(A)\neq\emptyset$. But this *means* that $f(x)\in\overline{f(A)}$.
2. The author proves that, for each $x\in\overline A$, $f(x)\in\overline{f(A)}$. But this means that $f\left(\overline A\right)\subset\overline{f(A)}$.

Comment: can you explain why or how f(x)∈ closure of f(A)

Comment: I explained that in my answer: every neighborhood of $f(x)$ intersects $f(A)$. That's what it means to assert that $f(x)\in\overline{f(A)}$.

Comment: okay I think I understand that now. But how does that mean that f(closure of A) is a subset of closure of f(A)

Comment: If you have two sets $X$ and $Y$, saying that, for each $x\in X$, $f(x)\in Y$, is the same thing as saying that $f(X)\subset Y$. So, since, for each $x\in\overline A$, $f(x)\in\overline{f(A)}$, $f\left(\overline{A}\right)\subset\overline{f(A)}$.

Answer (score 1):

You started with an arbitary point of $\overline{A}$. You then show

> Every neighbourhood of $f(x)$ intersects $f[A]$.

This is the definition of $f(x) \in \overline{f[A]}$.
And so $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$, as a point $f(x)$ as you started with is 
really an arbitrary point of $f[\overline{A}]$.

Comment: but it was only stated that x ∈ closure of A, why is f(x) a point in f(closure of A)

Comment: @NiangMoore That's the definition of $f[\overline{A}]$. Recall that $f[B] = \{f(x): x \in B\}$ for all $B \subseteq X$.

Comment: I see where my confusion lies. The definition of closure I'm using is the set and the union of its limits point. Is there a way to relate this definition to the proof.

Comment: @NiangMoore show that the definition I use: $x$ is in the closure of $A$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, is equivalent to $A\cup A’$. Show two inclusions between these sets.

Comment: Suppose x is not in closure of A. Since x is not in closure of A, it is not in A nor is it a limit point of A. Therefore there must be some neighborhood N of p that does not intersect A at all(N does not contain any point in A). Is this right? Should I start this on a new page as another question?

Comment: @NiangMoore and if $x$ is in “your” closure and $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, either $x\inA$ and $N$ intersects $A$ in $x$ already or $x \notin A$ and then $ x \in A’$ which also ensures $N\cap A\neq \emptyset$. So $x$ is in “my” closure in either case.

Comment: thanks, I get that. Can you write this as a proof

Comment: @NiangMoore We just gave a proof, right? What more do you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84210/discussion-between-niang-moore-and-henno-brandsma).